# Need help configuring php on nginx at openshift

Tags: php, nginx, configure, openshift

i'm newbie in openshift and nginx. This is my first experiment creating DIY app using php 5.5 on nginx. Nginx server is working perfectly, but when i add php-fpm configuration :

```
...
location ~ ^/index.php(/|$) {    
root html;    
include fastcgi_params; 
fastcgi_pass unix:${OPENSHIFT_RUN_DIR}/php-fpm.socket;    
fastcgi_index index.php;    
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME html/$fastcgi_script_name;    
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;    
fastcgi_intercept_errors on;  
}
...
```

in nginx.conf, I get 503 error on my browser telling service is unavailable. I had modify above script by many suggestion, but still no luck. Please anyone? Thanks

ps : I also had following https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/installing-php-fpm-and-nginx from github, but still no luck

Comment: what do your logs say? Try running "rhc tail <appname>" and paste in the output

Comment: After doing "rhc tail <appname>" seems there is error in variable name. Nginx doesn't recognize var $openshift_run_dir. I will going to resolve it. Thanks niharvey

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you creating a [Downloadable cartridge](https://www.openshift.com/developers/download-cartridges) instead of DIY. There are several nginx-php community cartridges on GitHub at the moment, eg. [OpenShift Nginx PHP-FPM Cartridge](https://github.com/getupcloud/openshift-nginx-php-fpm) by Getup Cloud, which you can spin up very easily with a single command:

`rhc app create php https://reflector-getupcloud.getup.io/reflect?github=getupcloud/openshift-nginx-php-fpm`

References:

- [OpenShift Origin Documentation Site](http://openshift.github.io/documentation/)
- [OpenShift Origin Cartridge Developer’s Guide](http://openshift.github.io/documentation/oo_cartridge_developers_guide.html)
- [Download and Run Your Own Cartridges on OpenShift](https://www.openshift.com/developers/download-cartridges)
- [List of OpenShift Origin community cartridges](http://app-shifter.rhcloud.com/) (an early instance of [oo-index, see it's GitHub repo](https://github.com/openshift/oo-index))